# Finger print authentication

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to authantication with finger print. I did not find anything about it.
Is there any example ?

> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html

this is Android 6.0+ i want to low level example so i want to authantication Android 4.0+

```
public boolean authentication(SomeClass auth)
{
//code block.
}
```

Comment: The Fingerprint Authentication is offered from Android 6.0+. It is not supported for lower versions.

Answer (score 2):

Fingerprint Authentication is only available from Android 6.0

Here is an example:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

Comment: I want to low level sir :( i just search it maybe i couldn't find it

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: https://dzone.com/articles/android-fingerprint-authentication-tutorial

Comment: It is not low level bro . Its Android 6.0+ too @Daniel RL

Comment: Sorry, Its only available to 6.0 or higher, not have support to lower versions.